# Reverse range over a string

Tags: string, loops, go

How can I "reverse range" in Go over individual characters of a `string`?
For example, given `s := "some string \u1222 whatever"` - I want to do something like:

```
for i, v := ~reverse~ range s {
}
```

Please note, that I'm interested in a solution via standard library without having to write a function myself. I'm aware of tons of existing libraries which can do that, but that's irrelevant. Moreover - I can't use `len(s)` and do:

```
for i := len(s) - 1; i >= 0; i-- {
}
```

since in Go built-in `len` function returns only number of bytes in a string (won't work for non-ASCII strings). I also can't do `len(s) - k - 1` where `k` is an index provided by `range` instruction due to aforementioned reason.

---

**UPD1**:
It is possible to do a reverse (right to left) lookup of `utf-8` `rune`s, because we can easily identify `rune`s by high order bits of each byte or groups of bytes. From `The Go Programming Language` book:
[image]
As you can see, we can start from the last byte and we will need to scan to the left at most 4 bytes to get a `rune`.

Comment: It is basicaly impossible to „reverse“ an arbitrary Unicode string.

Comment: The question is not how to "reverse", but rather how to access each individual utf-8 character in reverse order.

Comment: Okay, let me reword it: It is basicaly impossible to "access each individual utf-8 character [of an arbitrary Unicode string] in reverse order". Really. Combining characters and ltr/rtl and probably more I even do not know makes this task _impossible_. The problem lies less in "reverse" than "character".

Comment: @Volker, I've added an update section to my question where I explained how one can access utf-8 character in reverse order. In Go utf-8 runes are grouped in to 1, 2, 3, 4 bytes and each group's byte sequence has the same higher order bits for any character of the group. So, starting from the last byte and looking up at most 4 bytes will give us an utf-8 character. By the way, that's how DecodeLastRune works: https://cs.opensource.google/go/go/+/refs/tags/go1.17.3:src/unicode/utf8/utf8.go;l=247

Comment: You are conflating Unicode code points with „characters“. You are right that it is trivial to access code points in reverse order. But thats not „characters“.

Comment: But can't we convert code points (those bytes) to a rune which is a character basically? I would appreciate if you can explain the difference between a character and a rune.

Comment: U+0308 is not a "character". Neither is U+1F3FC. Which "character" is U+200D? Do you consider U+200F to be a "character"? Unicode is **complicated**. The whole idea of "character" is ill-defined. There are graphemes (the thing you see) and these are visual rendering of one or many unicode code points (call runes in Go).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest solution would be to convert the `string` to `[]rune`, so you can iterate over it, but index "backward" (or use a downward loop):

```
rs := []rune(s)
max := len(rs) - 1
for i := range rs {
    r := rs[max-i]
    fmt.Printf("%c ", r)
}
```

This will output (try it on the [Go Playground](https://go.dev/play/p/oYGftPhpFfy)):

```
r e v e t a h w   ሢ   g n i r t s   e m o s
```

If you want to avoid the `[]rune` conversion, you may use [`utf8.DecodeLastRuneInString()`](https://pkg.go.dev/unicode/utf8@go1.17.3#DecodeLastRuneInString) like this:

```
for {
    r, size := utf8.DecodeLastRuneInString(s)
    if r == utf8.RuneError {
        break
    }
    fmt.Printf("%c ", r)
    s = s[:len(s)-size]
}
```

This outputs the same, try this one on the [Go Playground](https://go.dev/play/p/dbnXfSGdN8g).

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
runes:=[]rune(str)
for x:=len(runes)-1; x>=0; x-- {
   // work with runes[x]
}
```